# Safari Extension Showing Popover Different Window

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

I'm trying to build a Safari Extension where when a user hits Command+B it will show the popover. Using the code below it works but always shows the popover on a different window not the current window/tab. I would like it to display the popover on the current window instead of switching to a different window and opening the popover there. It works perfectly if there is only one Safari window open but starts to have problems when multiple windows are open.

Any ideas?

**Global Page File**:

```
<script>
    safari.application.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        if (e.name == 'Show Popover') {
            safari.extension.toolbarItems[0].showPopover();
        }
    }, false);
</script>
```

**Injected Content**:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keydown);

function keydown(event) {
    if ( event.metaKey && event.keyCode == 66) {
      event.preventDefault();
      safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage('Show Popover', {});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are manually selecting the first toolbarItem here;

```
safari.extension.toolbarItems[0].showPopover();
```

You need to determine which toolbarItem the popover needs to appear on;

Something like this;

```
var toolBarID = 'my_id';
var activeItem = safari.extension.toolbarItems.filter(function (button) {
    return button.identifier == toolBarID && button.browserWindow == safari.application.activeBrowserWindow;
})[0];
```

You then use this object for the `showPopover` function;

```
activeItem.showPopover();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Great that looks like it worked!! Thank you very much for your help. One note is I did have to change `toolbarItemId` to my actual toolbarItemId. Would be nice if you could edit your answer to mention that just for future reference and for other users. Thanks again.

Comment: @CharlieFish No problem, and oops my bad - updated :)

Comment: Thanks again. Just so you are aware I will be awarding the bounty at the end of the 7 day period. :)